# No Data from my ddwrt router

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell

I have cisco e900 router, with dd-wrt firmware. I connect it to arduino uno-r3 + LCD 16*2 to show-up the status and some data from that router/ I am using TX-RX port in both sides.

The problem is: there is no data!!

arduino LCD just showing that > "dd-wrt - powerd cisco e900"

Are there any mistakes I made in my code?

Here's the arduino part:

```
// include the library code:
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
int led1 = 8;
float raw;
byte bl[8] = {
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
};
void setup(){
   pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
   lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.createChar(1, bl);
  lcd.createChar(2, bl);
  lcd.createChar(3, bl);
  lcd.createChar(4, bl);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("dd-wrt - powered");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("cisco e900");
}
void loop()
{
  int charcount;
  boolean secondline;
  if (Serial.available()) {
    delay(200);
    lcd.clear();
    charcount = 0;
    secondline = false;
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
      if (charcount > 15 && secondline == false ) {
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        secondline = true;
      }
      char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
      if (inChar != '\0') {
      lcd.write(inChar);
    }
       if (inChar == '\3') {
      digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
      }
       if (inChar == '\4'){
      digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
     }
      charcount++;
    }
  }
 }
```

and here's command on my router cisco e900

```
#!/bin/sh
I=`nvram get wl0_ifname`
SR="/dev/tts/0"
vr=`nvram get DD_BOARD`
stty -F /dev/tts/0 9600

while sleep 1; do

WIP=`nvram get wan_ipaddr`
NC=`grep 0x /proc/net/arp | grep br0 | wc -l`
DU=`uptime  | cut -c2-9`
UP=`awk '{print int($1/3600)":"int(($1%3600)/60)":"int($1%60)}' /proc/uptime`
LD=`uptime  | sed -n -e 's/^.*average: //p' |  sed s/[,]//g`
D1=`date +"%F"`
D2=`date +"%r"`
Rxw=`grep vlan1 /proc/net/dev | awk '{print ($2-l1)/1024"kB/s"}'`
Txw=`grep vlan1 /proc/net/dev | awk '{print ($10-l2)/1024"kB/s"}'`
Rxv=`grep eth1 /proc/net/dev | awk '{print ($2-l1)/1024"kB/s"}'`
Txv=`grep eth1 /proc/net/dev | awk '{print ($10-l2)/1024"kB/s"}'`
NET=`wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain`
ISP=`nslookup $NET | tr ' ' '\n' | tail -1 | cut -d. -f3`
IS="your_isp_home_page"
SP=`ping -c2 -W2 $IS | tail -1`
PM=$(echo $SP | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 1);
PA=$(echo $SP | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2);
PI=$(echo $SP | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 3);

  if [ -z `wl -i $I assoclist` ]; then
     echo -ne "\4" > $SR
    else
     echo -ne "\3" > $SR
  fi
  echo -n "$vr" > $SR
sleep 8

  echo -ne "$D1      $D2" > $SR
  sleep 3
    echo -ne "WAN IP:         $WIP" > $SR
  sleep 3
 if ! ping -c2 -W2 $IS > /dev/null; then
   echo -ne "$NC client        Internet DOWN" > $SR
   echo -ne "\2" > $SR
   nt=0;
 else
   nt=1;
   echo -ne "$NC client        Internet UP" > $SR
   echo -ne "\1" > $SR
   sleep 3
   echo -ne "Net IP:         $NET" > $SR
   sleep 3
   echo -ne "ISP:            $ISP" > $SR
 fi
  sleep 3
 if [ "$nt" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo -ne "Ping avg: $PA$PM/$PI" > $SR
  sleep 4
 fi
    echo -ne  "WAN RX:         $Rxw" > $SR
  sleep 3
    echo -ne  "WAN TX:         $Txw" > $SR
  sleep 3
    echo -ne "WLan RX:        $Rxv" > $SR
  sleep 3
    echo -ne "WLan TX:        $Txv" > $SR
  sleep 3
    echo -ne "Time $DU   UP $UP " > $SR
  sleep 3
    echo -ne "Load            $LD" > $SR
  sleep 3
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `echo` decodes escape sequences, this line for example is not working:

```
echo -ne "\1"
```

Try using `printf` instead.

Comment: hmm i am c programer, i have no idea what you mean :D ! did you mean to change all echos commands with printf !

Comment: @narzan: In C, string and character escape sequences are processed during parsing, and `\1` gets replaced by the actual character with ASCII code 1.  In shell, that doesn't happen, it's up to the individual commands to replace (or not) escape sequences with the corresponding characters.  The `printf` command does, while the echo command is going to send two characters, equivalent of C `"\\1"`

Comment: oh wow thanks allot, i will make some changes and i will back :)